# User input into a variable to be used in a later function

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I wanted to make a program that allowed the user to pick a stock ticker and other inputs, and then get real-time data that immediately went back into the program and would display the stock info and stuff.

The user should then be able to pick a stock and also a start and end date, and see some basic stock info from those dates. That code itself works, but I've been struggling with being able to use a GUI to provide inputs into the stock program.

```
from tkinter import *
#import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import random
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from optparse import OptionParser

compname = 'Company Name'
tckersymbl = 'Ticker Symbol'
strtdte = 'Start Date (y, m, d)'
numbday = 'Number of Days'


#fields = 'Company Name', 'Ticker Symbol', 'Start Date (y, m, d)', 'Number of Days'

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field = entry[0]
      text  = entry[1].get()
      companyname = entry[0]
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))


def makeform(root, tckersymbl):
   entries = []
   for field in compname:
      companyname = entry[0]
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

def fetch1(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field1 = entry[2]
      text1  = entry[3].get()
      ticker = entry[2]
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field1, text1)) 

def makeform1(root, tckersymbl):
   entries = []
   for field1 in tckersymbl:
      ticker = entry[2]
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field1, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES)
      entries.append((field1, ent))
   return entries

def fetch2(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field2 = entry[4]
      text2  = entry[5].get()
      startday = entry[4]
      startday1 = startday.int()
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field2, text2)) 

def makeform2(root, strtdte):
   entries = []
   for field2 in strtdte:
      startday = entry[4]
      startday1 = startday.int()
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field2, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES)
      entries.append((field2, ent))
   return entries

def fetch3(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field3 = entry[6]
      text3  = entry[7].get()
      numbdays = entry[6]
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field3, text3)) 

def makeform3(root, numbday):
   entries = []
   for field3 in numbday:
      numbdays = entry[6]
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field3, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES)
      entries.append((field3, ent))
   return entries

#companyname = entry[0]
#ticker = entry[2]
#startday = entry[4]
#startday1 = startday.int()
#numbdays = entry[6]

print(companyname)
style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(startday1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'iex', start, end)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df.head(numbdays)) #change value to change number of days you get. default is five


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry("350x175")
   ents = makeform(root, compname, tckersymbl, strtdte, numbday)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
   b1 = Button(root, text='Show',
          command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

   root.mainloop()





#compname = 'Company Name'
#tckersymbl = 'Ticker Symbol'
#strtdte = 'Start Date (y, m, d)'
#numbday = 'Number of Days'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_variable = input('enter your name: ') # Ari
print(my_variable)
>>> 'Ari'

my_variable = input('enter a number: ') # 10
print(my_variable)
>>> '10'

# Getting an actual integer, not as a string
my_variable = int(input('enter a number: ')) # 10
print(my_variable)
>>> 10
```